# The TSF(Text Service Framework) interfaces wait for windows logon?

Tags: windows, com, ime

I worked on a project about Input Method using TSF(Text Service Framework) of Microsoft. The process of my program was started by an auto-run service when Windows logon. 
I wrote the TSF api call like this:

```
HRESULT hr = _pInputProcessorProfileMgr->EnumProfiles(langID, &pEnum);
```

in which **pEnum** is an instance of *IEnumTfInputProcessorProfiles* and **_pInputProcessorProfileMgr** is an instance of *ITfInputProcessorProfileMgr*. Generally, this api enumerates all the registered profiles according to language ID.

However, the API call got nothing but profiles with GUID/CLSID "**00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000**". If I delayed the current thread for several seconds(by Sleep method), the API call returned the right profiles that I expected(and still included the profile with id = 0). It seemed the result of TSF API calling depended  on the some component's initialization.

Does anyone have any concerns about this? How can I know the TSF has been ready to work?

Comment: The COM obejct has been initialized.

Comment: The problem cannot be reproduced at Win7, but at Win8.1 & WinServer2012r2, is it a bug?